# a problem after "rosrun openni_camera openni_node"

Tags: ros, openni-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After I run the command "rosrun openni_camera openni_node",it shows as below:

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/bin/openni_node: relocation error: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference

Is there anyone who can tell me why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47121/a-problem-after-%22rosrun-openni_camera-openni_node%22/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient16
```

If the command above didn't work,  make sure to check that the update repositories are enabled by checking /etc/apt/sources.list, you may need [this](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Precise_Repositories).

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-10-30**:
it worked. Thanks!

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-30**:
Welcome :)